# superposition principle

Tags: circuit-analysis, superposition

[image]

In the first step, I just used source transformation to get Vr. But when I use the superposition principle for this circuit, I get the other answer. Please explain it to me.

Comment: I can't read your handwriting. This is a Q and A showcase site and, in my opinion, you should use the inbuilt schematic tools and make a much more readable and neater job.

Comment: Hint: the voltage across a resistor connected in parallel to an ideal voltage source (irrespective of other sources and connections) will be the voltage of the ideal voltage source.

Comment: Do NOT do source transformation if you are doing superposition.  Post original circuit and better quality workings.

Answer (score 2):

When you use supposition principles, you short circuit voltage sources and open circuit current sources and keep dependent sources as they are and use one active source at a time. Because voltage across the resistor is always constant, no more current can flow through it which is \$\frac{V}{R}\$ .
When Current source is open circuited, the current in the resistor is \$\frac{V}{R}\$ and its potential difference is V.
When voltage source is short circuited, current in the resistor is nearly zero and its potential difference is nearly zero.  The current in circuit flows according to how much impedance each wire has.

Your equations seem wrong because the voltage source has zero impedance and all current I from current source goes through voltage source in a practical circuit.

Using superposition principle, voltage across resistor is V.

Remember these properties of voltage and current sources.

A ideal current source can deliver current in any part of the circuit to obey KCL at any current junction.
A ideal voltage source can maintain a fixed potential difference at any part of the circuit even if it means delivering less current. All excess current from current sources goes through voltage sources instead of loads if current and voltage sources are in parallel.

Comment: As in, all of the current from current source flows through the voltage source.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I checked that in LT spice.

Answer (score -3):

This circuit is wrong. It has a logical-electrical-mathematical contradiction, which means it's impossible to solve with the simple assumptions that:

- wires have zero resistance
- voltage and current sources are perfect (have zero resistance)

The contradiction is in the fact that a perfect voltage source is connected directly to a perfect current source THAT DOESN'T NECESSARILY HAS THE SAME VOLTAGE ACROSS IT.
It means: a current source is a voltage source that adjust itself so a certain current flows through it. So in your circuit, Vr is the voltage of the voltage source and the voltage of the current source at the same time - contradiction.

Comment: There is no contradiction in the question as you have described it. A voltage source can be in parallel with a current source without contradiction. Let me give you a clue to where you went wrong... *Voltage sources have zero impedance but, current sources have.... (please fill in the gap)*